# Overlapping issue when trying to vertical center the text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

Currently im trying to learn `HTML` and `CSS` while using `Bootstrap-5`

I want to have a 2 line text in the vertical and horizontal center.
The issue is, I can't get it to align properly and it always ends up overlapping. I've spent an hour on this and can't figure out how to fix it.

Code:

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5.0.x -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<h1 class="fw-light position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle fs-1">Velkommen</h1>
<br>
<h1 class="fw-light position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle fs-4">HTX 2021 - 2024</h1>
```

Current result:
[image: picture of preview]

Comment: You're using position absolute...

Comment: remove either `position-absolute` or raise the `top-class`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`position: absolute;` is the completely wrong approach here. To center your text vertically and horizontally you should use [Flexbox](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/utilities/flex/)!

1. Wrap your elements in a container and apply `display: flex;` to it: `d-flex`.
2. To maintain the normal block-level element behavior use `flex-direction: column`: `flex-column`
3. To horizontally center the text use `align-items-center` and to vertically center the text: `justify-content-center`
4. To vertically center the text on the screen, the contaienr must have a height equal the screens height: That you can achieve with: `vh-100`

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5.0.x -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<div class="vh-100 d-flex flex-column justify-content-center align-items-center">
  <h1 class="fw-light fs-1">Velkommen</h1>
  <br>
  <h1 class="fw-light fs-4">HTX 2021 - 2024</h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just change one of the class from `top-50` to `bottom-50`

```html
<!-- Bootstrap 5.0.x -->
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">


<!-- Body -->
<h1 class="fw-light position-absolute bottom-50 start-50 translate-middle fs-1">Velkommen</h1>
<br> 
<h1 class="fw-light position-absolute top-50 start-50 translate-middle fs-4">HTX 2021 - 2024</h1>
```

Comment: it nworks nearly perfectlly. It is a little off. The bottom-white-space is a bit larger then the top. Thats due to the usage of absolute positioning that should be avoided since you have flexbox to vertically center clean.